# Run SQL script file from powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run queries stored in a text file from PowerShell. I use following to do that;

```
Invoke-Expression 'sqlcmd -d TestDB -U $user -P $pw -i "E:\SQLQuery1.sql"'
```

If an error or exception occurs when executing the queries from the `.sql` file, how can I capture that in my Powershell script? How can I get the script output?

NOTE: I cannot use `invoke-sqlcmd`

Comment: Why are you using `Invoke-Expression`?  Just call sqlcmd like normal.  `PS> sqlcmd.exe -d TestDB -U $user -P $pw -I E:\SQLQuery.sql1`.  If you are seeing an "error or exception" please post the full text of this error or exception.

Comment: You might also explain why you can't use invoke-sqlcmd. Maybe there's a workaround.

Comment: +1 for needing an explanation on `invoke-sqlcmd`. IIRC, if you've got a system where `sqlcmd` is installed, you'll also have `invoke-sqlcmd` (as long as it's the tools from SQL Server 2008+)

Answer (score 14):

To answer the question

> If some error or exception occurred when executing .sql file how can I get that into my PowerShell script? How can I get the script output?"

`Invoke-Expression` returns the output of the expression executed. However, it may only capture `STDOUT`, not `STDERR` (I haven't tested, as I don't use this method), so you might not get the actual error message.

From the Help:

> The Invoke-Expression cmdlet evaluates or runs a specified string as a command and returns the results of the expression or command

The better route is to use the PowerShell method you already have available - `Invoke-SQLCmd` is installed if you have installed any of the SQL Server 2008 (or newer) components/tools (like SSMS). If you've got SQL Server 2012, it's very easy: `import-module sqlps`. For 2008, you need to add a Snap-In, `add-pssnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin`. And since you have `sqlcmd.exe`, the PowerShell components should be there already.

If all else fails, go the `System.Data.SQLClient` route:

```
$Conn=New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection "Server=YOURSERVER;Database=TestDB;User Id=$user;password=$pw";
$Conn.Open();
$DataCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
$MyQuery = get-content "e:\SQLQuery1.sql";
$DataCmd.CommandText = $MyQuery;
$DataCmd.Connection = $Conn;
$DAadapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter;
$DAadapter.SelectCommand = $DataCmd;
$DTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable;
$DAadapter.Fill($DTable)|Out-Null;
$Conn.Close();
$Conn.Dispose();
$DTable;
```

With both this and `Invoke-SQLCmd`, you'll be able to use `try/catch` to pick up and handle any error that occurs.

Comment: See here if you have **GO** in your statement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25681013/1747983

Answer (score 12):

As seen in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619427/execute-sql-script-using-powershell-and-store-the-output-in-sql-file), there is a method built into Powershell to invoke SQLCMD called, unsurprisingly, `Invoke-Sqlcmd`.

It's very easy to use for individual files:

```
Invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $db -InputFile $filename
```

Or groups:

```
$listOfFiles | % { Invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $db -InputFile $_ }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `invoke-sqlquery` module, available at [this website](http://powershell4sql.codeplex.com/).